# mysql HOUR() accounting for timezones

Tags: mysql, sql, timezone

I have a query that returns results grouped by the hour, like so.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (`shipped_products`) WHERE HOUR(timestamp) = 8
```

The issue is, I get different results on localhost than on the live server. The data is exactly the same on both (UTC). I believe that my localhost database is New York while the live Database is UTC, and because of this, HOUR() is working differently on the two environments. I don't have permission to change the live server timezone, and would like to avoid changing the local database timezone. Is there a way inside the query to ensure the HOUR() function is returning the same results regardless of database timezone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just set the session timezone (or the global time zone) to UTC, [as described in the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html).

```
set time_zone = '+00:00';
```

Then `HOUR` and other functions will interpret `timestamp` types in UTC.  See also the differences between `timestamp` and `datetime` [in this part of the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html).

However, another concern is that `WHERE HOUR(timestamp) = 8` is going to make your query [non-sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), so it will have to scan the entire table, and won't be able to take advantage of any indexes you may have.  The more records in the table, the slower this will get.  (Especially if you have thousands or millions of records).

A better approach is to rewrite this as a *range query*.  Get the starting and stopping times you want to filter by, and use a half-open interval.

```
WHERE timestamp >= @start AND timestamp < @end
```

Of course, you will lock down the value to a specific date when you calculate the start and end values.  If instead you really do want the 8:00 UTC hour of *every* day, then you should create a separate integer column on the table with that information, so you can use it in a sargable query.

```
WHERE your_utc_hour_column = 8
```

This could be a computed column in some databases, but I don't think those are supported in MySQL, so you'd have to create and populate it manually.

Comment: As said in response to the previous question, that is hard coded, so if the difference between New York and UTC is not 5 hour, like it is for a few weeks during Daylight Savings Time, or during historical changes, the result will be wrong. As for your other point, it is very true, however this query is only to be used for a non critical stats page for staff, so speed is not an issue.

Comment: It's more than a few weeks - actually daylight time lasts longer than standard time in the US.  Regardless, you wrote in your question "The data is exactly the same on both (UTC)" - so if all your data is in UTC, then hardcoding the session time zone to UTC to match is a much better approach then trying to compensate for local time conversion.

Comment: I am a bit confused by the wording of your question though.  maybe I'm missing something.  Also, the accepted answer shows conversion from UTC to Eastern time, but I thought you were asking for the conversion in the opposite direction?  You seemed to indicate that the data was being shown in Eastern time and you wanted it in UTC.

Comment: UTC and New York change Daylight Savings at different points of the year, making hard coded "+ hour" logic fail on occasion. The data is in UTC, but since localhost MySQL is set to New York, the HOUR function interprets the timestamp as New York time.

Comment: Yes, I'm fully aware of how DST works.  But you're still not being clear about why New York matters to you.  If the *data* is in UTC, then the *data* should be interpreted at `+00:00`.  The time zone of the server should be irrelevant.  Setting the session time zone to `+00:00` takes care of that.  The fact that New York changes DST twice a year doesn't change that the data is in `+00:00`.  The only way it would matter is if the *data* was stored with regard to New York time, and you stated that it was in UTC.

Comment: The data is stored in UTC, but the server converts/interprets it as New York time when the `HOUR()` function is run on local MySQL because MySQL is in New York Time, or at least, that's how I understand the cause of behavior I am seeing, otherwise, I have no explanation for the difference from the local environment and live environment giving different results.

Comment: When you use `set time_zone`, it affects the behavior of the `HOUR` function (and others) - which is why I recommended you call `set time_zone = '+00:00';` before your query, so that the `HOUR` function returns the UTC hour instead of the New York hour.

Comment: Ahh, I understand now. You're correct, that does bring the expected result and brings consistency between my environments without hacks. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try the [`CONVERT_TZ()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (`shipped_products`)
WHERE HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(timestamp, 'UTC', 'America/New York')) = 8
```

The manual warns:

> ### Note
>
> To use named time zones such as `'MET'` or `'Europe/Moscow'`, the time zone tables must be properly set up. [See Section 10.6, “MySQL Server Time Zone Support”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html), for instructions.

You can also use hour values instead, but will lose any timezone knowledge such as historic timezone changes, DST, etc.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (`shipped_products`)
WHERE HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(timestamp, '+00:00', '-05:00')) = 8
```

Comment: For some reason this is returning now results, all the way from 0 to 23. I'll continue looking into this solution.

Comment: On the hour values alternative, it seems that will break during inconsistencies between New York and UTC on daylight savings time. I would add a disclaimer on that part.

Comment: If using named time zones, MySQL will be aware of DST as well as historical changes. What does "break" mean?

Comment: `'+00:00', '-05:00'` is hard coded, so if the difference between New York and UTC is not 5 hour, like it is for a few weeks during Daylight Savings Time, the result will be wrong.

Comment: Yes it will; that's why you should used named time zones.

Answer (score 0):

While Matt Johnson has the right answer, and miken32 has the proper answer for most situations, if you find yourself unable to change database permissions, unable to upload timezone tables, unable to do SET statements, and needing something that won't break during daylight savings changes, the following will work.

```
$corrected_hour = $hour;
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost') 
{
    $dateTimeZoneNY = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
    $dateTimeZoneUTC = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
    $dateTimeUTC = new DateTime('now', $dateTimeZoneUTC);
    $timeOffset = $dateTimeZoneNY->getOffset($dateTimeUTC);
    $corrected_hour = $hour + abs($timeOffset) / 60 / 60;
}
```

This will not break as long as both databases maintain their current timezone setting.